# SQLRT TESTCONNECTION 2 returns 1 -What could be possible problem

Tags: sql-server

I am using this function SQLRTTESTCONNECTION2() to connect to SQL server.
Its returning me as value 1 ,which means failure to establish a connection.
What could be possible cause for this?Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server is setup to allow remote TCP/IP connections (off by default) and you have eliminated firewall issues, try to connect with something ([SQL mngmnt. studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796)) that will give you more detail than "**FAIL**".